# Group and Count Duplicate values in C# List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have a list of strings like this:

```
List<string> myList = ["black", "red", "green", "green", "red", "green", "blue"]
```

I want the return to be group by the string and the count to be how many times it appears in the array, ordered by count:

```
{
  "green": 3 (because there's 3 "greens" in the list
  "red": 2
  "black" : 1,
  "blue" : 1
}
```

How can I achieve this with LINQ? I've tried groupby's with count's but I'm not getting the right syntax.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you had tried and didn't work? This gives a foundation to start from in order to help why it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to fix your list initialize to

```
List<string> input = new List<string> { "black", "red", "green", "green", "red", "green", "blue" };
```

Then you can use below to get a `Dictionary` which `Key` is the color and the `Value` is counts.

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => new
{
    y.Key,
    Count = y.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Count);
```

Comment: This will be ordered by the occurrence of the "key" while creating the Dictionary and not by the total count descending - e.g, `black, red, green, blue` and not `green, red, black, blue` as desired by the op.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that part

Comment: Almost there! The ordering needs to be on the "Count" and not the "Key" - also, it's not explicitly required to use `ToDictionary` based on the original question, omitting it will also give the assumed desired result. It might also be worth providing additional color commentary on why this solution works as a learning exercise for the op given current troubles.